# Put php logic function inside wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that displays an content to to users who have an paid subscribtion:

`echo do_shortcode('[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_who="5,7"] MY CONTENT HERE [/ihc-hide-content])`

But I want to display inside this shortcode where it says MY CONTENT HERE, an logical function, like this:

```
if ( $a = $b ) {    echo ($c);    }
```

There is possibile to do this in some way?
P.S. I have made another shortcode, and put him inside like this:

```
do_shortcode('[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_who="5,7"].do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]').[/ihc-hide-content])
```

But the 1st shortcode is not hide the content of 2nd shortcode.
Any help will be apreciated, ans sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an [Enclosing Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes) you should just be able to add the shortcode as a string to your [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function. `do_shortcode()` will search the content that's passed to it and parse out any and all shortcodes that it's able to. Depending on *how* the `ihc-hide-content` shortcode is set up, it *may* not work quite properly, but you can get around that as well.

First and foremost, I would try just passing a single shortcode string to it:

```
do_shortcode( '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_who="5,7"][my_shortcode][/ihc-hide-content]' );
```

If that doesn't work (in all honesty, it should) - you can try and generate the output from `my_shortcode` into an [Output Buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) like so:

```
// Turn on Output Buffering
ob_start();

// Output your shortcode
do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode]' );

// Turn off Output Buffering, and grab the content as a variable
$my_shortcode_output = ob_get_clean();

// Pass that complete output to the other shortcode
do_shortcode( '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_who="5,7"]'. $my_shortcode_output .'[/ihc-hide-content]' );
```

Comment: You are right! There was the problem! I must pass a single shortcode string, not with php code! Thhank you! This work for me `do_shortcode( '[ihc-hide-content ihc_mb_who="5,7"][my_shortcode][/ihc-hide-content]' );`